# Is Homeo$(X)$ a topological group?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, topological-groups

I am working on a problem involving the rotation number of an orientation-preserving circle homeomorphism, which induces a map $\rho : \text{Homeo}^+(S^1) \to S^1$. It is well-known that this is a continuous map if we give $\text{Homeo}^+(S^1)$ the uniform topology.

Since $\text{Homeo}^+(S^1)$ (and more broadly, the full space of homeomorphism $\text{Homeo}(S^1)$) has a group structure via composition, I am wondering if it is a topological group, meaning that composition and inversion are coninuous maps.

More generally, if $(X,d)$ is a compact metric space, then $\text{Homeo}(X)$ is actually metrizable by way of the sup metric $\rho(f, g) = \max\{d(f(x), g(x)) : x \in X\}$ which induces the uniform topology. **My Question: Is $\text{Homeo}(X)$ a topological group under composition and the uniform topology?**

I think this is true, but I am having trouble showing it using $\epsilon-\delta$ with the sup metric. Does uniform continuity come into play at all?

Comment: Function spaces, such as this one, are often given the compact-open topology.

Comment: Sure, but if I recall correctly, that coincides with the uniform topology for compact metric spaces.

Comment: sorry I thought your question was how to topologize the set in general.

Comment: It is pretty much a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/173093/homeomorphisms-of-x-form-a-topological-group

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks, that's very helpful. But I do still wonder how a proof by $\epsilon-\delta$ would go. I'll see if I can't work out the details using that linked question